# Cannot step into referenced assembly code during debug

Tags: c#

I created a C# Project. I added a reference to that in my WAP project.  I've used some classes and methods from the C# Project in the code-behind of one of my .aspx pages in my WAP project.  I'm not able to step into the code that resides in my C# project from my code-behind.

When I set a breakpoint, the method is called but I can't step into it. The method is in my C# Project which is referenced by binary into my WAP project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the c# application by project (import into solution) instead of by referencing the .dll file, if that is what you're doing now, and make sure that the solution and project configurations are set to build the c# project in a debug configuration (optimizations off).